# laravel query - call to underfined property - collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to attach some data to a view and have been able to do this a number of times with success. However my latest page is throwing an error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$pay_method
```

In my controller I have the following query:

```
$receipt = Receipt::where('invoice_id', '=', $id)->get();
```

$id is a variable holding the invoice id.

I'm passing the object to the view as follows:

```
return View::make('greenfee.edit')
        ->with('receipt', $receipt);
```

In the view - to test I am simply doing:

```
{{ $receipt->pay_method }}
```

'pay_method' being a column in the table.

This throws the error.

To test further I've tested $receipt contains data using print_r and the property is definitely there - here's an extract:

```
[pay_method] => card
```

and is the value I would expect.

So - what am I missing and misunderstanding here?

Also - when should I (or not) use get() on a query?

All help appreciated
Ta

Comment: `Receipt::where('invoice_id', '=', $id)->get();` returns array of objects (collection) . So when you get the collection you are calling pay_method on the collection which doesn't exist in laravel collection. What you need to do is iterate through receipts in the view.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the info - I changed to first() as below and works great. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Collection is basically an array of results, so you would have to iterate over it with a for loop or something.
However, If you are trying to just fetch one record/row you should use:

```
$receipt = Receipt::where('invoice_id', '=', $id)->first();
```

Comment: Hi - makes perfect sense now - thank you. I didn't fully understand the difference, especially as I expected only one result to be returned. code revision works great - thanks